# UML диаграммы в Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uml

Всем привет!
Возникла необходимость в создании UML диаграммы классов в среде разработки Xcode 6.3.2.

Удалось найти решение только для старой версии программы.

http://www.developers-life.com/tag/uml

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли способ создания UML диаграммы классов  в последних версиях Xcode ?

Answer (score 3):

Я не совсем знаком с UML, но если Вам необходимо показать ориентированный граф зависимостей между классами на Objective-C, то можно использовать вот этот плагин [KSHObjcUML](https://github.com/kimsungwhee/KSHObjcUML) для Xcode 6.3.2

Так же можно посмотреть и этот плагин [ObjectGraph-Xcode](https://github.com/vampirewalk/ObjectGraph-Xcode)

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно, потому как данные плагины не показывают информацию о свойствах и методах конкретного класса. Но это решает часть проблемы. Спасибо.